# Can't add stroke to shape in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to add a simple dashed stroke to a `Rectangle` in SwiftUI, but nothing I've tried works:

```
VStack {
   Rectangle()
      .fill(Color("Dark Gray"))
      .strokeBorder(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 4, dash: [15.0]))
      .cornerRadius(4)
}
```

The compiler complains:

`Value of type 'some View' has no member 'strokeBorder'`

Why is this happening when `Rectangle` is of type `Shape`, not `View`?

Comment: Fill returns a View. 
func fill(style: FillStyle = FillStyle()) -> some View.  This is where the order of your modifiers makes a difference.

Comment: Of course. The syntax makes it so difficult to remember that the modifiers are wrapping things rather than just applying properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something like this, to have both `strokeBorder` and the `fill` color:

```
   Rectangle()
      .strokeBorder(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 4, dash: [15.0]))
      .cornerRadius(4)
      .background(Rectangle().fill(Color("Dark Gray")))
```